# Is each time and activity starts a new object of that class created?

Tags: android, oop, android-activity

For example, if I do:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, OrderScreen.class);
    startActivity(intent);
```

will a new object of OrderScreen class be created ? And if i return back to first activity and go back to OrderScreen class, will the same object being retrieved or another one?

I have been working with android for almost 1 year now and its almost crazy how I just thought of this now.

Answer (score 2):

yes each time you do and intent it will give you a new instance of that object. unless you set a Flag to the Intent such as the `FLAG_REORDER_TO_TOP`, if you add it as a flag then it will take the old instance of OrderScreen and add it to the top of the activity stack..